# Import date from postgresql to neo4j

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, neo4j

I am trying to import data from my local PostgreSQL database to neo4j

Firstly, I load the JDBC driver into memory

```
CALL apoc.load.driver("org.postgresql.Driver")
```

Then, I run this query to ingest data from postgresql

```
   WITH "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/graph-test?user=kt" as url
   CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url,"os.operating_systems") YIELD row AS line
   MERGE (o:Os {name: line.name})
   MERGE (of:OsFamily {name: line.familly})
   MERGE (o)-[:FROM]->(of)
```

Unfortunately, I received this error.

```bash
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.jdbc`: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Could this error be caused by the incorrect URL, jdbc plugin version, or something else?

Comment: What about the password?

Comment: I've tried including or excluding the password, neither option works for me....

Comment: your question title is wrong :) yes either user credentials or the database is not listening on localhost but only on loopback. does it work when you use other SQL tools that use the same connection string